# How to force xip files to use Archive Utility?

Tags: xcode, file

When I try and open a `.xip` file macOS always opens it in TextEdit instead of Archive Utility even though the file is an archive.

The main file I'm having an issue with is the `xcode.xip` which is from Apple's website.

Answer (score 3):

In Finder:

1. Select the file
2. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt/opt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
3. The file inspector opens. Press the triangle for 'Open with:' and select Archive Utility.
4. Select 'Always open with' and confirm the dialog box.

Comment: it's command + i.

Comment: Yes, CMD + I does the same. Using CMD + OPT + I has the advantage that you  can use the same shortcut again to close/hide it. If you click off of it you need to press CMD + O a second time and then CMD + W to close it. :)